# On the app engine development server why does the "Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore" step take several seconds?

Tags: google-app-engine

It seems like something that should take place in a flash, at least locally. Is there some time emulation of the production server that causes it?

Comment: In my experience it sometimes is very fast but occasionally if there are a few queries running it takes awhile

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much data is saved in your local datastore and how fast your disk is.  I've noticed if you have a lot of deleted data in your datastore, the file still ends up being big.

If you want to clear the database, it's better to delete the whole file than delete all the individual entities.